# C# code is not analysed by SonarQube scanner for MSBuild

Tags: c#, jenkins, msbuild, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

SonarQube counts the c# lines in our projects, calculates the coverage and the duplications, but does not check for issues or code smells.
For example, the following silly code does not generate any code smell :

```
public static bool Silly()
        {
            int neverUsed = 0;
            var foo = false;
            foo = !!foo;
            var bar = "toto";
            bool isTrue = true;
            int one = 0;
            if (isTrue)
            {
                one = 1;
            }
            System.Console.WriteLine(one);
            if (bar != null & bar.Substring(0, 2).Equals("to"))
                return true;
            return false;
        }
```

We checked the c# quality profile (vanilla Sonar Way). There is no file exclusion. The analysis is working well with javascript code.

We are using :

- SonarQube 6.7.5
- Jenkins 2.74
- SonarQube plugin for Jenkins 2.6.1
- SonarQube scanner for MSBuild 3.0.2
- MSBuild 14
- SonarC# 6.2

We followed :

- [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Jenkins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins)

Here my jenkins build's configuration (vanilla) :

[image]

In the build log, we found :

- La cible "RunCodeAnalysis" répertoriée dans un attribut BeforeTargets à "D:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\NouveauProjet.sonarqube\bin\targets\SonarQube.Integration.targets (356,11)" n'existe pas dans le projet et sera ignorée.
- WARNING: Failed to fix Code Analysis ErrorLog file. Please check that VS 2015 Update 1 (or later) is installed.

Comment: The first warning probably means FxCop isn't installed on your build machine. Either way, it won't affect the Roslyn analysis. The second warning is relevant. Roslyn analysis reports are written as json files. However, the v1 of Roslyn produced invalid json in some cases. The scanner checks that the file is valid json and if not attempts to correct it. This warning suggests that analysis is being performed but producing an invalid file the scanner can't fix. Check the produced json report is actually valid json. MSBuild 15 has a newer version of Roslyn that doesn't have this issue.

Comment: @duncanp That's it! To install MSBuild 15 as a stand alone, we had to install VS Build Tools. Thank you very much. You should post your comment as a answer.

Comment: no problem - glad it worked. I'll move the comment to an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first warning relates to FxCop, and probably means FxCop isn't installed on your build machine. It won't affect the Roslyn analysis.

The second warning is relevant. Roslyn analysis reports are written as json files. However, the v1 of Roslyn produced invalid json in some cases. The scanner checks that the file is valid json and if not attempts to correct it.

This warning suggests that analysis is being performed but is producing an invalid file the scanner can't fix. Check the produced json report is actually valid json. MSBuild 15 has a newer version of Roslyn that doesn't have this issue.

[Update] MSBuild 15 is installed with the Build Tools for  Visual Studio 2017, available [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017)